# asp tag not recognized in asp.net content place holder

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, master-pages

I am using Master page for my web form, I am facing a issue like I am not getting any asp.net controls and what ever typed not able to recognize as asp.net controls

```
       <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
       </asp:Content>
       <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" Runat="Server">
        <div>

         <table>
            <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" ></asp:Label> //'asp' Unrecognized name space
            </td>

        </tr>
       </table>
      </div>
    </asp:Content>
```

I didn't understand why  it is not recognizing. please help me anyone.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I have edited. please check my question @Rahul

Comment: Can you post your master page code

Answer (score 0):

Check your `web.config` and see if you are missing the below segment. If missing, add them. Also, I assume there is something wrong in your master page itself. Post your master page code.

```
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```